# using window.open inside setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I want to create a timer that will reload extensions every 10 minutes.

This works, except the window doesn't open. I tried it with www.google.com as well

any thoughts?

```js
var count = 0

var jsUpdatePageTimer = setInterval(updatePage, 5000)

function updatePage(){
    console.log(count)
    if (count == 3) {
        console.log('count is 3')
        clearInterval(jsUpdatePageTimer)
    } else {
        console.log('updating count')
        window.open('http://reload.extensions')
        count +=1 
    }
}
```

Comment: hah, wait a second — are you actually *trying* to create popup spam? thankfully the browser can thwart this

Comment: hah, no, i have a script that is crawling a website (i legally have access too) but cookies get invalidated every 20-30 minutes. I have a chrome extension that deletes the cookies, refreshes the page, saves new cookies, stores to a db (that my scraper reads from)

Comment: well, perhaps instead of a popup, you could inject an iframe onto the page which does the same work? there are popup blockers, but no iframe blockers... maybe just disable your popup blocker, though

Comment: im a lot less familiar with writing iFrames. any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

popup blockers like to block calls to `window.open` — you may remember the terrible days when javascript could open popups willy-nilly

nowadays, for `window.open` to work, you have to use it within a user-initiated call stack

which means, you can only use `window.open` as the result of a user-triggered event, like a mouse click

```
button.onclick = () => {
  window.open(/*...*/)
}
```

so you need to ask yourself: what is the relevant user action that should trigger this popup? you need to have the user's consent

Comment: its a chrome extension just for me, not meant for anyone else

Comment: oh, maybe just disable your popup blocker?

Comment: oh hah yea, that did it! didn't even see that the popup blocker was stopping it

Comment: Will appreciate a proof-link.